# Compilation failed : nothing to repeat at offset 19 (preg_match)

Tags: php, preg-match, offset

I have the following simple code which check if the password contains at least two lowercases.

```
preg_match("/^(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])+$/")
```

But this gave me the following error message:
**Compilation failed : nothing to repeat at offset 19**.

I can't figure where I'm wrong

**Later Edit**

The following code which checks if i have at least two special characters works well:

> `preg_match("/^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*].*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z_!@#%^&*]+$/"`)

Answer (score 2):

The `(?= )` defines an assertion, you can not repeat an assertion. Did you mean to use `(?: )`?

```
$data = array('ab', '123a345b', '123');

foreach ($data as $subject) {
  $found = preg_match("/^(?:.*[a-z].*[a-z])+$/", $subject, $match);
  var_dump($found, $match);
}
```

Output:

```
int(1)
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "ab"
}
int(1)
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "123a345b"
}
int(0)
array(0) {
}
```

Comment: sorry..but this gives wrong result...now when I enter two lowercases it tells me that i didn't.

Comment: i have the followong code `preg_match("/^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*].*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z_!@#%^&*]+$/")` which works fine for at least two special characters

Comment: I expanded the source to a full example. It matches if two lowercase a-z are found. The (?:) avoids the capturing of the subpattern.

Comment: i think that my problem is that i have three separate preg_match functions for the same input password...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
preg_match("/^(.*[a-z].*[a-z].*)$/", "2313123g123123u123", $result);
var_dump($result);
preg_match("/^(.*[a-z].*[a-z].*)$/", "65665656s656565", $result);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

result

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
        string(18) "2313123g123123u123"
    [1]=>
        string(18) "2313123g123123u123"
}
array(0) {
}
```